# docker: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root: not found

Tags: mysql, docker

Скачиваю docker pull mysql Захожу в интерфейс и запускаю контнейнер из образа, получаю ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не запускается контейнер так как не указан MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD. Как его указать, чтобы контейнер запустился?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:5.6
489eb212211364890376e134e49899e089ab3559d2375ac1d96ba9ce16df5e95